# Total Stock by product category In Woocommerce reports

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy, stock

I am trying to get Total Stock Valuation by Category in Woocommerce.

Anyone have a clue how this can be done?

I know it's a simple code but I just can't figure it out.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED:**

*Not simple at all…* **but I get it**. See the screenshot below:

[image]

**1) GET THE DATA AND CALCULATE:**
Here is a custom function with a bit complex SQL query that will get for each product category all the related products stock quantity. Then in a foreach loop, I add the stock quantities by product category to get the Total Stock Valuation by Category.

```
/**
 * Get the Total Stock Valuation by Category.
 *
 * @param integer $category_id (optional)
 * @return an array with the category ID (int) as key and total stock quantity (int) as value
 */
function get_product_cats_stock_qty( $category_id = 0 ){
    global $wpdb;


    // The DB tables involved
    $term_tax = $wpdb->prefix . "term_taxonomy";
    $term_rel = $wpdb->prefix . "term_relationships";
    $postmeta = $wpdb->prefix . "postmeta";

    if( 0 != $category_id )
    { // get one defined category
        $one_category_only = "AND $term_tax.term_id LIKE $category_id";
    } else 
    { // get all categories
        $one_category_only = '';
    }

    // Query all detailed categories and related product stock quantity
    $results_obj = $wpdb->get_results("
        SELECT  $term_rel.term_taxonomy_id as cat_id,
        $term_rel.object_id as prod_id, $postmeta.meta_value as stock_qty
        FROM  $term_rel, $postmeta, $term_tax
        WHERE  $term_rel.object_id = $postmeta.post_id
        AND $term_rel.term_taxonomy_id = $term_tax.term_id
        $one_category_only
        AND $term_tax.taxonomy LIKE 'product_cat'
        AND $term_tax.count > 0
        AND $postmeta.meta_key LIKE '_stock'
        AND $postmeta.meta_value != ''
        ORDER BY $term_rel.term_taxonomy_id ASC
    ");

    // Iterating though each categories / products relationships stock quantity
    foreach($results_obj as $result){
        // Initialising each different category stock
        if( empty( $stock_qty_by_cat_id[ $result->cat_id ] ) )
            $stock_qty_by_cat_id[ $result->cat_id ] = 0;
        // category stock quantity calculation
        $stock_qty_by_cat_id[ $result->cat_id ] += intval( $result->stock_qty );
    }
    return $stock_qty_by_cat_id
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

**2) ADMIN REPORTS STOCK SECTION CUSTOM TAB:**

Here are the functions that will add a custom tab with the corresponding custom content: You will get a list of all product categories and for each of them all the related products stock quantity sum.

```
// Add a Custom tab to admin repport stock section
add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_reports', 'add_my_custom_stock_admin_report', 10, 1 );
function add_my_custom_stock_admin_report( $reports ){
    $reports["stock"]["reports"]["category_stock_valuation"] = array(
        'title'       => __( 'Category Stock Valuation', 'woocommerce' ),
        'description' => '',
        'hide_title'  => true,
        'callback'    => 'content_custom_stock_admin_report',
    );
    return $reports;
}

// The content for the Custom tab to admin repport stock section
function content_custom_stock_admin_report( ){

    ?>
    <div id="poststuff" class="woocommerce-reports-wide">
        <table class="wp-list-table widefat fixed striped stock">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col" id="cat_id" class="manage-column column-category-id column-primary"><?php _e('Term ID','woocommerce'); ?></th>
                    <th scope="col" id="cat_name" class="manage-column column-category-name"><?php _e('Category Name','woocommerce'); ?></th>
                    <th scope="col" id="stock_level" class="manage-column column-stock_level"><?php _e('Stock count','woocommerce'); ?></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="the-list" data-wp-lists="list:stock">
                <?php
                    foreach( get_product_cats_stock_qty() as $cat_id => $cats_stock_qty  ):
                        $cat_name = $cats_stock_qty['cat_name']; // category name
                        $stock_qty = $cats_stock_qty['stock_qty']; // Stock quantity
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td class="category-id column-category-id column-primary" data-colname="Product"><?php echo $cat_id; ?></td>
                    <td class="category-name column-category-name" data-colname="Parent"><?php echo $cat_name; ?></td>
                    <td class="stock_level column-stock_level" data-colname="Units in stock"><?php echo $stock_qty; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col" id="cat_id" class="manage-column column-category-id column-primary"><?php _e('Term ID','woocommerce'); ?></th>
                    <th scope="col" id="cat_name" class="manage-column column-category-name"><?php _e('Category Name','woocommerce'); ?></th>
                    <th scope="col" id="stock_level" class="manage-column column-stock_level"><?php _e('Stock count','woocommerce'); ?></th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested on WooCommerce 3+ and works.

Comment: how would it be possible to display this on the front end of website say on top of the category page rather than in the admin area

Comment: this code gives me the table but only populates the category ID, the category name and stock levels are empty... is there any update or fix?